# Control Tab-Key behaviour in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a form in excel and now want to jump from cell to cell by pressing the tab key but only between cells in which the user shall enter the data. A solution is to lock the sheet and only leave the fields unlocked in which the user shall enter something. However, this doesn't work with fields containing merged cells (which I need) and it also struggles if a merged field is allocated over multiple lines located next to a "single entry cell". The tab key then simply jumps back to the previous cell and doesn't move forward.

Therefore I need to "manually" control the behaviour of the tab key and came across the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "TabIntercept"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
End Sub
```

Above works to trigger an event when TabKey is pressed. Now I need help in writing the function TabIntercept to send the tab-key to the next entry-cell in my form. Say I have 5 fields in B3, B8, D3, E3, E6 in which data shall be entered.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub TabIntercept()

    Const TAB_ORDER As String = "B3,B8,D3,E3,E6" 'entry cell addresses in tab order
    Dim arr, a, x, nxt, sel

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub 'Exit if (eg) a shape is selected
    Set sel = Selection.Cells(1) 'if multiple cells selected use the first...

    arr = Split(TAB_ORDER, ",")
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If sel.Address(False, False) = arr(x) Then
            'loops back to start if at end...
            nxt = IIf(x = UBound(arr), LBound(arr), x + 1)
            Range(arr(nxt)).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: using named ranges would be very similar -

```
Sub TabIntercept2()

    Const TAB_ORDER As String = "tabs1,tabs2,tabs3,tabs4,tabs5"  'as named ranges
    Dim arr, a, x, nxt, sel

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub 'Exit if (eg) a shape is selected
    Set sel = Selection.Cells(1) 'if multiple cells selected use the first...

    arr = Split(TAB_ORDER, ",")
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If sel.Address() = sel.Parent.Range(arr(x)).Address() Then
            'loops back to start if at end...
            nxt = IIf(x = UBound(arr), LBound(arr), x + 1)
            sel.Parent.Range(arr(nxt)).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Works perfectly. Now one more thing: if I define a name for a field or a merged range, e.g. B3 named as "field_seller" and B8 as "field_buyer" while B8 is a merged range of B8:B9, how would I have to amend your script? I tried to replace B3 with the defined name but it did not work.